# Find if a string is contained within another string in R

Tags: r, string, loops, if-statement

I am trying to find if a string is contained in another string in a different dataframe. I am using if statements and for loops and I want to keep the structure as I have it but just can't find the correct syntax to use. 
An example of my first data frame is:

```
Route1
x y z
w x f z 
a b c
x y z
```

An example of my second data frame is:

```
Route2      Track
x y z        A
v w x f z    B
a b          C
```

Once I have found whether Route1 is contained in Route 2 I want to assign Route 1 the corresponding Track. Hence the final data frame for data frame 1 should be:

```
Route1   CalculatedTrack
x y z     A
w x f z   B
a b
x y z     A
```

The formula I current have is:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(df2)){
    if((((grepl(df1$Route1[i], df2$Route2[j],perl = TRUE)==TRUE){
      df1$CalculatedTrack<-df2$Track[j]
    }
  }
}
```

Hence I want to loop through each row to see if Route1 is in any of Route2. Note that I have multiple columns in each data frame.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have a look at `?merge` in base R or in the `data.table` package if speed is an issue.

Comment: For merge don't the "Routes" need to be identical?

Comment: You are right, sorry, had overseen that you are looking for partial matches also. Then you might need `%like%` and from `data.table` also.

Comment: Is the order of your partial match of interest, hence, in Route 1 you might have " c d e" and in Route 2 you might have two entries like "b c d e" and "c d e f", should both be matched and how to deal with the situation that these two Route 2 entries have different tracks?

Comment: 'x y z' matches both track A and B.  What rule to decide which you want?

Comment: @ManuelBickel the order is important yes

Comment: @dww ops good spot! I have changed it

Comment: is your question still not answered? if so mark it please as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In data.table syntax, we can do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[, Track := df1[, df2[grepl(Route1, df2$Route2), Track[1]], 1:NROW(df1)][,V1]]
```

Note that if multiple matches of Track are found for any row, this assumes that the first match will be used

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat hacky solution, but works nonetheless

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tribble(
  ~route1,
  "x y z",
  "w x f z",
  "a b c",
  "x y z"
)

find_route_match <- function(string, df2){
  df2[str_detect(df2$route2, string), 2] %>% as.character()
}

df2 <- tribble(
  ~route2,        ~track,
  "x y z",        "A",
  "v w x f z",    "B",
  "a b",          "C"
)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(match = map(route1, find_route_match, df2)) %>% 
  unnest()
```

which produces the following output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
   route1        match
    <chr>        <chr>
1   x y z            A
2 w x f z            B
3   a b c character(0)
4   x y z            A
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `fuzzyjoin` package:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

regex_right_join(df2, df1, by = c(Route2 = 'Route1'))
#      Route2 Track  Route1
# 1     x y z     A   x y z
# 2 v w x f z     B w x f z
# 3      <NA>  <NA>   a b c
# 4     x y z     A   x y z
```

Reproducible data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Route1 = c("x y z", "w x f z", "a b c", "x y z"
)), .Names = "Route1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(Route2 = c("x y z", "v w x f z", "a b"), Track = c("A",
"B", "C")), .Names = c("Route2", "Track"), row.names = c(NA,
-3L), class = "data.frame")

df1
#    Route1
# 1   x y z
# 2 w x f z
# 3   a b c
# 4   x y z

df2
#      Route2 Track
# 1     x y z     A
# 2 v w x f z     B
# 3       a b     C
```